# Visual Studio Code VSCode Debugging/Compile C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have some questions to debug and compile in VSCode for `C++`.

I have installed the `c/c++`addon from Microsoft.
After this, I started Debugging and chose `c++` (Windows) as debugging mode.
Which program I have to choose for this line in the launch.json file?

```
"program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceRoot}/a.exe"
```

The next problem is how to configure the C++ compiler to compile out of Visual Studio Code.

Comment: shouldn't this be tagged just vscode, visual studio itself doesn't seem to be related to the actual question?

Comment: I have not attempted to compile C++ code on VSCode, however, I know that you need to specify the path to your compiler program, be it GCC/Clang/MinGW/MSBuild and then properly setup the environment so that Code can look for it and the necessary libraries to correctly compile and run your program. VSCode comes with no compiler by default so there is no automatic setup for this.

Comment: Recent changes look promising: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/10/24/building-your-c-application-with-visual-studio-code/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to find the relative path to whichever program you'd like to debug let's call the executable, "example.exe" that's located in /exampleProj/debug/ relative to your workspace root which is whichever folder you opened to start VS Code(if you're not sure where it is go back to the navigate sidebar and locate the file from there).

you'll then want your progam entry as follows:

```
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/exampleProj/debug/example.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like it is asking you to choose the name for your executable - you need to choose a name.  I am not familiar with VSCode.  In VStudio, you would right-click on the project, select properties and under the linker it would be the field for the output file.